# Best Android photo editing apps?

Tags: photo-editing, android, software-recommendation

What are the best photo editing applications for an Android camera phone such as the Nexus One, Droid, Droid Incredible, HTC Evo, etc...

Please list the advantages or disadvantages of the application and why do you think it's the best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is specifically a list-type question, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with Photoshop Mobile app it seems the best that I've tried so far.

Comment: In what way is it the best?

Answer (score 4):

**[Camera360](https://market.android.com/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360&hl=en)** for sure!

Reasons :

- Effect like LOMO, Retro Effect, Dreamlike Effect, Art of Black and White, Back to 1839 and Night Enhancement will make your photo more beautiful.
- The amazing HDR effect is even better than iPhone HDR.
- Unique Funny Mode: Effects like Surrealistic B&W Paining, Vertical/Horizontal Left Symmetry, Vertical/ Horizontal Right Symmetry, Ghost are available.
- Unique Scenery Mode: It takes the interesting composite photos, you can choose whether be in a movie poster, an art painting, a outdoor advertisement, or among the various types of greeting cards.
- Unique Tilt-shift and Color-shift Mode allows you to see the world from another angle.
- Share your photo to Sina Microblog, Facebook or Twitter

Comment: + 1 for listing reasons, @mattdm I believe that someone should offer a bounty for this question to get more valuable answers

Comment: @Akram: go for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Streamzoo. (I am a founder.)

There is a review here: [Meet The Best Alternative To Instagram – Streamzoo [iPhone & Android]](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/meet-alternative-instagram-streamzoo-iphone-android/), and you can get it from [the Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.phonezoo.android.streamzoo).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit why you believe this to be the best app?

Answer (score 1):

[**PicsPlay Pro**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybus.fx) is an amazing photo editing app for phones.

Some of the main reasons I went with this app:

- **Curve Editing** - All / Red / Green / Blue / Black & White
- **White Balance**
- **Histogram Editing** - Much like *Levels* editing in Photoshop

And of course it has all the other basic editing that most phone apps have; hue/saturation, brightness/contrast and so on.

It has other additional features such as adding borders, vignettes and textures to you photos as well as a really large library of effects like HDR, vintage and B&W. There's also a handy *comapare* button that allows you to temporarily switch to the original image to compare the changes you're making.

It has sharing capabilities, which I have not used, so I cannot comment on that part of it but if it's anything like the rest of the app I'm sure it works quite well.

Why PicsPlay Pro over other apps with similar capabilities? User Experience. They did a good job of making everything easy to use and understand. I would suggest the [trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybus.fxfree) which limits you by not giving you as many effects and you can only work with photos at the minimum resolution.

[Awesome Miniature Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybus.tiltshift) by the same developers is also worth trying. Again, [free trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybus.tiltshiftfree) available as well. It's a fairly powerful tilt-shift photo creator that is really easy to use and has some of the more basic editing capabilities of PicsPlay.

With an app like PicsPlay Pro, it's actually quite possible for a photo to go from capture to share without it ever leaving your phone.

I would also recommend getting [Instagram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android) now that it's on Android but not for it's editing capabilities. It has a few preset effects you can add to a photo, a faux HDR type feature and some frames but the main purpose of Instagram is sharing. It's a photo sharing app but in its simplest form and I believe that's what made it such a success.

Answer (score 0):

[Camera Zoom FX](http://www.androidslide.com/camerazoom) does some interesting effects if you don't mind the cheesy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

PicSay and Photoshop.com Mobile are both pretty good.

Comment: How are they good?

Comment: Please expand on this answer; it isn't very useful as it stands.

Answer (score -2):

You could find something useful at the [Flickr App Garden](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/search/?q=android&w=applications).